# Java: How to initialize and fill final static ordered Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, initialization, hashmap

I have a stemming algorithm in Java which requires a static final `HashMap<String, String>` pre-filled with about 30 000 records.

I need the map to keep records in the same order they are inserted (I got a hint I could use `LinkedHashMap`?).

I thought I could manually insert the values in the Java class file since this is the quickest way to load them in RAM (time / productivity is very important for this project) by using 30 000 calls like

```
map.put("Key", "Value");
```

The problem is, that java (or at least eclipse) allows only 65kb of code in any segment / method etc. So I ended up extending 11 classes and putting 65kb of `.put`s in a constructor or a `static { }`.

Everything was fine, but when I run it the order is scrambled. For so many rows I cannot track where did things go wrong, in the extending order or in the map.

So, please tell me what is the best way you would fill a final map in java with regards to performance.

P.S.: Loading and parsing the records from a file is far too slow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Everything was fine, but when I run it the order is scrambled. For so
>   many rows I cannot track where did things go wrong, in the extending
>   order or in the map.

a) A HashMap doesn't preserve insertion order. Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead.
Or, since you will use it as a constant, consider a Guava [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html). It preserves insertion oder, is immutable and provides a builder object for constructing it with many values.

b)

> P.S.: Loading the records from a file is far too slow...

Why? It would only be done once, during class load time. And 35K String / String pairs is really not a lot of data for a modern machine.

Comment: Yes, I talked about that in the question, but it's still scrambled.

Comment: @Tony ...because one [likely] needs look no further than `a)` (which was "talked about in the question" -- so do it already :-/) Also, it doesn't really matter *when* the HashMap is created ... it's the same one-time upfront cost.

Comment: @pst true, but having a class file with 35000 lines of static initialization sounds like hell to me, so I'd go for b) myself!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I would fix that issue (the 35k line static initialization) ... first. Creating a singleton Map or a static Map is really the same thing: it is created once. The difference is the source, which can be just about anything, from hard-coded calls (in the above case) to a monolithic string (if you want to keep it all "in the class file"), or CSV file or SQLite DB or whatnot. Make sure to run a *performance analysis* in correct context before chasing hypothesized performance gains at loss of clarity. (In both cases the result is the equivalent Map object created on the heap.)

Comment: *unlike HashMap, ImmutableMap is not optimized for element types that have slow Object.equals(java.lang.Object)* - I have to do a call to `.equals()` on each String in the map, so I suppose I should better go with LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Alright, I will make a quick speed test of loading from a file and I'll go with it if it isn't too slow, Thanks!

Comment: @pst, `ImmutableMap` provides insertion ordering.  Even for `String`, I would use `ImmutableMap` for this application, no question.  That said, I would never in a million years put 30000 lines of static initialization in a class file.  Load it.  Please.

Comment: @Tony: `String`'s `equals()` method is plenty fast. I would start with an `ImmutableMap` myself, and only use something else if it was measurably too slow.

Comment: It turns out that loading from a file is even faster than extending 11 classes.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to use in memory database?(e.g HSQLDB) It doesnt look right to pre-fill a class with so many data.